# How to set height of tableview cell while using UITableViewDiffableDataSource (Like heightForRowAt)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I was wondering to check how to set the height of tableview cell while using DiffableDataSource. This is code:

```
func configureDataSource() {
    dataSource = MenuItemDataSource(tableView: MenuItemTablevVew, cellProvider: { (tableView, indexPath, menuItem) -> UITableViewCell? in
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier) as? MenuItemTableCell else {  fatalError("Cell not exists")
        }
        
        cell.data = menuItem
        return cell
    })
    
}

func createSnapshot(menuItems: [MenuItemModel]) {
    var snapshot = MenuItemSnapshot()
    snapshot.appendSections([.First])
    snapshot.appendItems(menuItems)
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as for a traditional data source. What's the actual difficulty? You can use heightForRowAt if you want to.

Comment: heightForRowAt is not working.

Comment: Then show it, and your other table view configuration code. The use of a diffable data source is totally irrelevant to the matter.

Comment: above code is the only code that I'm using.

Comment: You have to implement the delegate as usually but you ave to use the new API to get the desired item from the indentifier. Example:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        if let item = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) {
            switch item {
            case .color : return 100
            default     : break
            }
        }
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }